# How to resume from debugger without interrupting the entire test in protractor?

Tags: debugging, gruntjs, protractor

I am writing a test using protractor. I am able to enter the debugger if I put the following code in my tests:

```
browser.pause();
```

However, I am not able to quit the debugger and resume the test execution.
According to [this documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md):

> When you finish debugging, exit by pressing Ctrl-C. Your tests will continue where they left off, using the same browser.

Actually, even the debugger itself tells me the same when it pauses:

```
------- WebDriver Debugger -------
 ready

press c to continue to the next webdriver command
press d to continue to the next debugger statement
type "repl" to enter interactive mode
type "exit" to break out of interactive mode
press ^C to exit
```

That all sounds good, but when I try Ctrl-C, it interrupts the entire test. What am I doing wrong?

I'm running the protractor test using grunt-protractor-runner@1.2.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says in the message, you can use

> press d to continue to the next debugger statement

and an entire suite will continue execution until it meets another debugger invocation (so you have to press 'd' one more time) or until the very end of the suite.

Note: `press d` actually means that you type in letter 'd' and hit 'Enter'

Comment: Ooops, apparently I cannot read.. 'd' is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: If you are from 2018, then use `^D` (CTRL+D).